# How do I put jsonObjects that are getting created on loop to a jsonArray and get that response in jsonArray?

Tags: json, spring-boot

This is the objects that are getting created, how do I put these objects that are being created on an array?

```
for (int i = 0; i < productsJSONArray.length(); i++) {

    productOrder = new ProductOrder();

    JSONObject productJSONObject = new JSONObject();
    productJSONObject = productsJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

    String _productPostId = productJSONObject.getString("productPostId");
    int productPostId = Integer.parseInt(_productPostId);

    ProductPost productPost = new ProductPost();

    productPost = productPostService.getProductPostByIdAndToken(productPostId, "ACTIVE");
    if (productPost != null) {
        productOrder.setProductPost(productPost);
    }

    productOrder.setUser(user);
    productOrder.setToken("ACTIVE");

    productOrder.setTransactionId(Long.toString(startTime));
    productOrder.setUnit(productJSONObject.getString("unit"));
    productOrder.setIceQty(Float.parseFloat(productJSONObject.getString("iceQty")));
    productOrder.setQuantity(Float.parseFloat(productJSONObject.getString("quantity")));
    PostStatus postStatus = postStatusService.getPostStatusById(Integer.parseInt(productJSONObject.getString("postStatusId")));
    if (postStatus != null) {
        productOrder.setPostStatus(postStatus);
    }
    productOrder = productOrderService.addProductOrder(productOrder);
}
```

I want to put these `productOrder`  objects inside an jsonArray

Answer (score 0):

Use the GSON lib to convert your productOrder object into JSONObject and add that JSONObject to Jsonarray.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
//loop starts here
ProductOrder order  = new ProductOrder();
//logic to populate the order
String orderString =  new Gson().toJson(order);
JSONObject JSONObject = new JSONObject(orderString);
array.put(JSONObject);
//loop ends here
```

In your case the array will initialised outside the loop and the element is added in the loop by converting it into the JSONObject.